# What ActiveX control does meta.stackoverflow.com keep trying to run?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

My IE security settings reject it (and all ActiveX controls) of course, but I'm curious — what ActiveX control is this site (and Server Fault) trying to run?

Note: It doesn't always happen. Something connected to the ads perhaps?

[image: caught it on superuser.com]

Comment: Any particular reason why you've scrubbed out your user name and rep?

Comment: @[Kyle Cronin]: I originally tried to host the image on flickr, but it didn't work so I moved it to...uh...somewhere else, i think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably throwing a hissy fit because of high security settings triggered by the inclusion of jQuery.

JQuery bugs:
**IE7 wants to run ActiveX add-on**

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4017
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4651

Comment: Sounds the most plausible; I've seen IE whine about jQuery before...

Comment: Noticed that on the second ticket (4651) some enterprising spammer posted their herbal links.

Comment: i see the same symptoms on twitter.com, this would explain it - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We don't use any ActiveX controls, can you clarify what it is you're referring to?

EDIT: we have looked ad this and we have no idea what IE7 "thinks" it is blocking. Any ideas?

Comment: caught one, see image in question edit. scanned through html on client-side but saw nothing that looked like an activex control... unfortunately IE is fairly obtuse about what it thinks it is blocking

Comment: captured html from a page, can download from http://www.filefactory.com/file/ahg75a7/n/SO-AX_html

Comment: it's probably jquery...though it only happens about 1 time in 10

Comment: the funny thing is - stackoverflow.com is a trusted site, so the activex control must be coming from a different domain!

Comment: do you think it's reacting to our hosting of jQuery at Google?

Comment: It's probably reacting to jQuery period, regardless of where it's hosted.